# Google Chrome Devtools not showing highlights correctly

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

For some reason, Chrome Devtools not showing the elements highlights on the correct place in the responsive mode. Its happening with all elements
Is is just me or its happening with someone else as well? Its happening after the new update i.e Version **73.0.3683.86** (Official Build) (64-bit)
[image: Wrong highlighting screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried setting the zoom to 100%? That's what I did and it fixed this problem.